# Where to place try/catch in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Where to place the try/catch so that it can work as expected, particularly, **when parallel branches exist**? (BlueOcean plugin is also there)

In the official doc of Jenkinsfile, there's nothing about this topic explicitly, examples do exist though:

Example 1: Try{} is inside the stage block

```
Jenkinsfile (Scripted Pipeline)
node {
stage('Example') {  //It's inside the stage block
    try {
        sh 'exit 1'
    }
    catch (exc) {
        echo 'Something failed, I should sound the klaxons!'
        throw
    }
}
}
```

Example 2: Try{} is inside the node block

```
Jenkinsfile (Scripted Pipeline)
stage('Build') {
    /* .. snip .. */
}

stage('Test') {
    parallel linux: {
        node('linux') {
            checkout scm
            try {
                unstash 'app'
                sh 'make check'
            }
            finally {
                junit '**/target/*.xml'
            }
        }
    },
    windows: {
        node('windows') {
            /* .. snip .. */
        }
    } 
}
```

**But does my implementation work**? It's a nested parallel build,  try/catch{} is the outermost block, see below:

```
try{
    parallel 'b0': {
        node('parallel'){
            ....
        }
    }, 'b1': {
        node('parallel'){
            ....
        }
    }, 'b2': {
       parallel 'b2-0': {
           node('parallel'){           
               ....
           }
       }, 'b2-1': {
           node('parallel'){
             ....
           }
       }, failFast: true

       parallel 'anotherb0': {
           node('parallel'){
                .....
           }
       }, 'anotherb1': {
           node('parallel'){
               ....
           }
       }, failFast: true
    }, failFast: true
}catch(err){
    print err
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
}finally{
}
```

The problem is that sometimes **when one of the branches fails, the whole build continues and the pipeline chart stays green** in BlueOcean, but this is not what I want; instead, I'd like to have it **fail the whole build** as soon as any branch fails. How can I do that?

Answer (score -2):

Declarative pipeline is recommended over scripted pipeline.

You would concentrate on writing to the specific pipeline syntax support provided by each plugin you wish to use.  Each one has similar but specific syntax to achieve their particular purpose.

That said sometimes you have to write little pieces of script in a script block.  I have never used a try catch and doubt you should ever need to if you follow the syntax support provided by each plugin which should be documented for each individually on the plugin site.

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage ("Do Something") {
            steps {
                bat "..."
                script {
                  //Code that requires a script tag to be present if it can't be done by a plugin's native pipeline support.
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```