# Jenkins declarative pipeline for simple basic code

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to fetch the code from the git and then run it on Jenkins. Currently, I am running Jenkins on a windows machine. But this code giving me an error "Not a valid stage section definition:"

```
pipeline {
        agent any
    
        stages {
            stage('Hello') {
               try
               {
                   git 'https://github.com/AnikQUPS/learning.git'
                   sh "python3 python.python"
               }
               catch(err)
               {
                   echo err
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48331473/where-to-place-try-catch-in-jenkinsfile ?

Comment: Nope thanks @ewong

Comment: Declarative DSL syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In declarative pipeline, you need to enclose `try-catch` inside the script{} block.

So, your pipeline should be like this:

```java
pipeline {
        agent any
    
        stages {
            stage('Hello') {
               steps {
                  script {
               try
               {
                   git 'https://github.com/AnikQUPS/learning.git'
                   sh "python3 python.python"
               }
               catch(err)
               {
                   echo err
               }
              }
             }
            }
        }
    }
```